# Integrate Swift into an exported Unity project instead of using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unity-game-engine

I am currently starting an iOS project and I want to use Unity as the primary drive for the project. Currently when you export Unity as an exported project, I am only given Objective-C.

> How do I make a Unity based project using primarily Swift?

This seems extremely complicated as Objective-C can develop in top level and most of Unity is involved with the top level, how can I use Swift in this project? I am planning on using most of the Unity in Objective C and most of the front end GUI on Swift.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a good couple of days hammering at this, it is possible. The main pitfalls was of course how the linking and the compilation process that Objective-C and Swift have to interact in order to do so:

1. Create an AppDelegate in Swift, subclassing UnityAppController and utilizing startUnity instead of Application(..)
2. Bridge between Swift and ObjectiveC using Unity's generated main.mm and the bridging headers
3. Create an Objective-C wrapper whose sole responsibility is to communicate between the Swift project and the Unity project

As follows here: https://apollowprogrammingblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/how-the-heck-do-you-integrate-swift-and-unity/

UPDATE July 11th 2016: There is also another guide, which I have since started using for my app development moving forward: https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5. This is a different approach and also largely more maintainable due to the easily configurable unity.xcconfig (To get through most of the project config headaches) strat used here